# Give a function to an icon in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, icons, textfield, kivy-language

I want to give a function to an icon entered in a TextField, I want to give it the typical function that has the 'eye-off' icon of passwords that when you press the icon change the function 'password' to False and the icon change to 'eye-on', and if I press it again, change to True and the icon returns to 'eye-off', let me explain, this is my main code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton, MDIconButton
from kivy.lang import Builder
from helpers import *



class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Yellow'
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'

        btn = MDRectangleFlatButton(text='Confirmar', pos_hint= {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.35},
                                    on_release= self.show_data)

        self.username = Builder.load_string(username_helper)
        self.contraseña = Builder.load_string(contraseña_helper)

        screen.add_widget(self.username)
        screen.add_widget(self.contraseña)
        screen.add_widget(btn)
        return screen

    def show_data(self, obj):
        print(f'Usuario: {self.username.text}\nContraseña: {self.contraseña.text}')

if __name__=='__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

and here I have my files in string mode which is the helpers module that I imported:

```
username_helper = '''
MDTextField:
    hint_text: 'Usuario'
    required: True
    helper_text: 'Enter text'
    helper_text_mode: 'on_error'
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 200
'''

contraseña_helper = '''
MDTextField:
    hint_text: 'Contraseña'
    password: True
    icon_right: "eye-off"
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.43}
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 200
'''
```

With this configuration, when typing in a password, some string appears with asterisks, but I want that by pressing the 'eye-off' icon that is on the right, I can see the string I am typing, and if I press it again hide again with the '*' and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by extending `MDTextField` like this:

```
class MyMDTextField(MDTextField):
    password_mode = BooleanProperty(True)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if self.icon_right:
                # icon position based on the KV code for MDTextField
                icon_x = (self.width + self.x) - (self._lbl_icon_right.texture_size[1]) - dp(8)
                icon_y = self.center[1] - self._lbl_icon_right.texture_size[1] / 2
                if self.mode == "rectangle":
                    icon_y -= dp(4)
                elif self.mode != 'fill':
                    icon_y += dp(8)

                # not a complete bounding box test, but should be sufficient
                if touch.pos[0] > icon_x and touch.pos[1] > icon_y:
                    if self.password_mode:
                        self.icon_right = 'eye'
                        self.password_mode = False
                        self.password = self.password_mode
                    else:
                        self.icon_right = 'eye-off'
                        self.password_mode = True
                        self.password = self.password_mode

                    # try to adjust cursor position
                    cursor = self.cursor
                    self.cursor = (0,0)
                    Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.set_cursor, cursor))
        return super(MyMDTextField, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def set_cursor(self, pos, dt):
        self.cursor = pos
```

This over-rides the `on_touch_down()` method of `MDTextField` and checks if a touch occurs in the vicinity of the icon. If so, it toggles the icon and the `password` setting of the `MDTextField`.

You can use this in your `kv` as:

```
contraseña_helper = '''
MyMDTextField:
    hint_text: 'Contraseña'
    password: True
    icon_right: "eye-off"
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.43}
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 200
'''
```

Comment: Just one problem, when i write the password in asteriks mode, if i press the eye icon to show me the password without asteriks, the line that indicates where you are writing shows in the position on the asteriks no in the position of the password with letters, 
so I see the line above the password with letters.
I don't know if I explain

Comment: I'll attached the 'before - after' image to show you better what I'm trying to explain:

https://imgur.com/3UJru9J

Comment: That's a bug in `TextInput`.

Comment: You know how to fix it?

Comment: I have actually looked at the code, and the numerous possible settings in `TextInput` make calculating the cursor position quite complex. I wasn't able to come up with a fix.

Comment: I had an inspiration after reading that some changes to the `TextInput` might not show up immediately. I have added some code to trigger recalculation of the cursor position.